# mapping many-many relationship kodo jdo 4.2 xml

Tags: mapping, jdo

I have the following in my package.jdo file

```
        <field name="entitlements" table="LEAFENTITLEMENT"/>
            <collection element-type="Entitlement"/>
            <join>
              <column name="LEAFID" target-field="ID"/>
           </join>
           <element>
             <column name="ENTITLEMENTID" target-field="ID"/>
           </element>
```

the DB relationship is that we have 3 tables
Entitlement - primary key id
Leaf - primay key id
LeafEntitlement - leafid,entitlementid - both foreign keys to respective tables
This is part of the mapping for the Leaf Table. I am getting a classCastException when trying to Enhance this using kodo.ant.PCEnhancerTask.
The collection is a set of entitlements for the Leaf Table. 
Thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a trailing **/** in your field tag

```
<field name="entitlements" table="LEAFENTITLEMENT" />
```

try removing it.